# Wordpress Contact Form 7 - Attachment field issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having trouble with the file/attachment field of CF7 plugin.

I set the field to accept only pdf and doc files, but I can still select an xml file without errors.

However, the most serious problem is that I do not receive any attachment anyway.

I add the field in my form with this shortcode:

```
[file file-198 filetypes:doc|pdf id:form-attach class:form-control]
```

Then I pasted [file-198] in Attachment field but nothing to do..

I also tried using the Google SMTP but no attachment is sent, perhaps not even loaded.

Can anyone give me some help?

Thanks so much :)

P.S. If needed I can provide more information

Comment: is email getting sent ? or it is failing?

Comment: Yes the mail is delivered correctly, only missing the attachment

Comment: Deactivate and delete contact form 7 plugin and then reinstalling it, most probably this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) plugin. It has email log. It will tell you what content the mail has. Also try enabling debug in `wp-config.php` and see if there is some error that occurs when the email is sent.